# passing data directly from one PC to another connected to the internet

Tags: wireless-networking

what are the ways in which we can share data/messages/information from one PC to another directly without the need of an intermediary server which are connected to the internet?

Comment: If both PCs posessed behind NAT without proper poкt mapping or DMZ set, then you cannot connect them without some external helper node at all.

Comment: so even P2P architectures aren't *really* P2P at all?

Comment: P2P term has a lot of meanings.

Comment: basically something like bitTorrent is what I meant,

Comment: p2p in torrent needs an external server for to init p2p connection (using UDP hole punching, for example). Once the connection is established the external server is no longer needed.

Comment: is this the external server is what they called a *tracker*?

Comment: I think that is true (it may be one of tracker's functions), but I'm not sure (I don't use torrent).

Comment: SSH, OpenVPN, etc.  The only thing that would need to be done for the aforementioned would be a DNAT port redirect rule on each PC's router to allow traffic going to port X to be directed to the RFC1918 IP or MAC the PC.

Comment: are router's rule writable by endusers? and what do you suggest reading for knowing these sort of things?